# Automating Java Applet from IE and VBA

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, applet

Is it possible to read from applets running in IE through VBA and to automate them (clicking buttons, selecting options etc.)? Would applet elements form some kind of a navigable DOM structure (ChildNodes, parnt etc.) and would functions like getElementById() work? If not, how else can we read from / automate applets?

Comment: Hello, did you found a answer for that?
I Having the same problem