# Automate Javascript form in Internet Explorer with VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, automation

I have a question similar to this one:

[Automating Java Applet from IE and VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936899/automating-java-applet-from-ie-and-vba)

which has no answer, as of yet.

I'm trying to automate filling in the form on the front page of [degreedays.net](http://www.degreedays.net/).

I'm using VBA so I can integrate my automation/scraping with excel easily.

I think the relevant source code of the page is:

```
<h2 class="popout">Degree Days.net</h2>
    <div id="formSlot">
        <div class="formLoading">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            // <![CDATA[
            document.write('<p><img src="template/loading-small.gif" width="16" height="16"/><span class="loadingText">Loading...</span></p>');
            // ]]>
            </script>
            <noscript>
            <p class="noJavaScript">To use Degree Days.net, your browser must have JavaScript enabled.  This should only require a very simple change to your browser settings.</p>
            </noscript>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But I have no way of using the typical VBA for forms, for example:

```
    ie.document.getElementById("   ").value= "   "
```

as there are no `<input>` or `<option>` tags visible to me.

How would I go about doing this? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: i believe you could use external driver, like imacros, or selenium

Comment: When you use "view source", you're looking at the page source as delivered from the server: in this case you need to use the IE Developer Tools to view the "rendered" source.  Then you'll see the form elements you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I work for the company that runs [Degree Days.net](http://www.degreedays.net/).

In case you haven't noticed, we have an [API here](http://www.degreedays.net/api/).  Programming something to fetch data out of the API is going to be a lot easier and more reliable than trying to scrape data out of the website.

We also have a [desktop app](http://www.degreedays.net/desktop/) that enables you to specify a big list of locations and then get the app to download it all for you, into a spreadsheet, using the API.  No programming required.